How to Display MediaType Image Response on HTML
I am returning an image source from my local file with MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG. I am able to see the image if I make a call via Postman, but I could not succeed displaying it on HTML.
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}/download")
  public ResponseEntity<Resource> download(@PathVariable UUID id, @RequestParam String key) {
    try {
      final Path file = Paths.get(String.format("%s/%s", "app/resource", key));
      final Resource resource = new UrlResource(file.toUri());

      if (resource.exists() || resource.isReadable()) {
        final HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
        httpHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", resource.getFilename());

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(httpHeaders)
            .body(resource);
      } else {
        // error
      }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      // error
    }
  }

I tried to display it without converting, but the HTML shows that the image is broken

<img :src=imageContent />

const { data } = await download(id, "test.jpeg");
this.imageContent = data;


I also tried to convert it to base64, but it didn't work.

<img :src=imageContent />

const { data } = await download(id, "test.jpeg");
this.imageContent =
      "data:image/jpeg;base64," +
        Buffer.from(data, "binary").toString("base64");

I am not sure where I made a mistake. Do I need to refactor my backend code? How can I display the image that I return as a response?

"also tried to convert it to base64, but it didn't work." - error, unexpected output, sat around picking its nose and talking back while waiting to get drop kicked?

how ist the download function implemented? are you sure data is actually an image binary?

@catch23 I've changed my approach to handle files. I am now using cloudinary to upload it to cloud instead of storing it in local

@Eniss so you haven't checked the posted answers?

I have, but none of them solved it.

I would use decoding as a BLOB object :

    const { data } = await download(id, "test.jpeg");
    this.imageContent = 
      "data:image/jpeg;base64," +
        Buffer.from(data, "binary").toString("base64");

    // atob() of JavaScript to decode the base chain64 in a binary chain
    const decodedImageData = atob(this.imageContent); 
   
    // Create a BLOB object
    const blob = new Blob([decodedImageData], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
    
    // Create a blob object URL
    const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    this.imageURL = imageURL;


And then establish the URL of the image on the image label:
    <img src="{{ imageURL }}" alt="Image description">


Thanks for the answer, but I am having the same output as my 2nd approach

Try to use folliwng MediaType: APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.
This MimeType should behave like Content-Disposition had already as attachment. Thus, you don't need to set it.
It will look something like:
// check if exists and is readable
InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));

return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .headers(headers)
        .contentLength(file.length())
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .body(resource);

Also, you could use ByteArrayResource:
// prepare steps
Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(path));

return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .headers(headers)
        .contentLength(file.length())
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .body(resource);


In order to expose static content you can replace your controller with:
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**")
                .addResourceLocations("app/resources/**");
            //    .addResourceLocations("file:/var/imageFolder/"); // alternatively read from disk (no need to wrap images in jar)
    }
}

the above code will expose http://localhost:8080/images to server static content from jar or disk (including sub folders)
this will allow you to do something like:
<img src="/images/your-key.jpg">

this is a simplified solution. for a large scale system it is better to serve static content via CDN.

As you have already mentioned your response contains image which is in the format of svg and then u have used the formatting which convert it to base 64 . If you're trying to display an SVG image using a Base64 string.
Use like this
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,YourBase64StringHere" alt="Description of the image">

